# How to write to KDE's OSD or notification from console?

Tags: bash, kde, osd, notifications

How can I write, from a bash script, to KDE's OSD or notification area? I am using KDE 4.5, and basically what I want is my script to report some stuff when it is run. Since I run the script by a shortcut, I have no console output, but I would like to write to OSD on notification area.

I know about, and use, "osd_cat" but that just puts some ugly text on the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually, the answer to "How … kde4 … from the shell" starts with `qdbus`. I would expect something like `qdbus org.kde.knotify /Notify event "notice" "my script" '(' ')' "title" "body" 0 '(' ')' 1000 0` to work, but it produces no visible effect on my Ubuntu 10.04 kde 4.4.2.

Comment: By the way, this is what passes for the API documentation: http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdebase-runtime-apidocs/knotify/html/classKNotify.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
notify-send 'why hello there'
```

`notify-send` is part of the package `libnotify-tools`.

---

```
perl -MDesktop::Notify -e'Desktop::Notify->new->create(body => q{why hello there})->show'
```

[`Desktop::Notify`](http://p3rl.org/Desktop::Notify) is available on CPAN.

Comment: unfortunately, it's no longer a part of libnotify4 :-/  kdialog below still works.  This is not a fault of daxim, just KDE's shifting libraries...

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative:

```
kdialog --passivepopup 'why hello there' 5
```

5 is the number of seconds it will last.
Run `kdialog --help` for other options, like `title`.

Comment: Don't even need to install any additional packages, and has all the options you would need, great! :-)