# How to send notifications from a bash script

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, kde-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write to KDE's OSD or notification from console?](https://superuser.com/questions/174885/how-to-write-to-kdes-osd-or-notification-from-console)

Hi,

i want to send a notification to the kde4 notification area (in desktop panel) from a small script. Is there a program for?
I cant find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try [notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/notify-send.1.html).

**Edit**: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379804/activating-kde-4-notifications-from-bash-scripts/1379834) too.